# want to add a popup screen with drawerlayout

Tags: android

i want to add a pop screen with in drawerlayout. the screen will give yes or no option before exit. now i have this code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: didnt get ur use case SIR!!

Comment: y do u want to add pop up to ur drawer instead u can have it on ur acitvity UI

Comment: i just want to add onbackpressed method in my mainactivity. when someonce click back button. screen will ask 'do you want to quit'. when the user clicked yes then app will close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here u go; in ur activity having drawer do this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //super.onBackPressed();
//i have commented out the super so that app wont destroy immediately
    askBeforeExit();
}

private void askBeforeExit() {

    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    String title = "Confirm Exit";
    String message = "Are u sure u want to exit";

    dialogBuilder.setTitle(title);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
    dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Nope", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Yeah sure", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //if okay exit the app
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });

    dialogBuilder.create();
    dialogBuilder.show();
}
```